# Can't commit large file to svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, centos, centos6

We have installed svn in an centos 6 system. We are accessing it through tortoise svn on windows systems.

When I tried to commit a flash FLA file of 5MB, I got this error:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
PUT of
'/svn/flash/!svn/wrk/ebed7841-7475-c84f-b2b4-ebdee28719ef/trunk/main.fla':
Could not read status line: connection was closed by server
(http://192.168.3.15)
```

I succesfuly committed a file smaller than 1MB . What's the problem with larger files.. is there any way to change the upload size

Comment: Sounds more like networks problems...

Comment: Read apache log, we can't see it from here

Comment: [error] [client 192.168.3.6] Could not get next bucket brigade  [500, #0]   i got this error in httpd/error_log

Comment: i got the error . actually it's the kaspersky internet secuirity in my system which blocks tcp connection. i just gave full permission and it's works

Comment: Could you add an answer and accept it later? This may be something others will search for as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the error . actually it's the kaspersky internet secuirity in my system which blocks tcp connection. i just gave full permission to svn client and it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Its the box or network, something is stopping it from completing - this is nothing really to do with SVN.

I used to have the same issues with a very slow VM box that was underpowered with RAM. Very large commits would be killed with the same error.